# Redirect to php page if index does not exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

Is it possible (using .htaccess presumably?) to automatically redirect `blah.com/hello` to `blah.com/hello.php` if `blah.com/hello/index.php` does not exist?

But if there is an `index.php`, I'd still like to show that without redirecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if /foo/index.php is not a file    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.index.php !-f
#then redirect /foo to /foo.php
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work just fine :) are there any limitations/caveats of this method that I should be aware of?